# Mavericks and Yosemite marks mails in multiple accounts as read

Tags: email, macos

I have 2 accounts configured in my Mac mail. alex@ and orders@

If for example I receive an e-mail with TO: alex@ and CC: orders@ it will go to both e-mail addresses. So far so good, but when I read only one copy (either from alex@ either from orders@) the mail app marks as read both of them.

This is happening even if I have Gmail account or Yahoo it does not matter the server.
Any idea of how to stop this? I just need to mark as read the e-mail I read from the specific email account, not from all of them.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. This is a very bizarre way for Mail to behave. In my testing, it is the only mail app that does so. It will mark identical messages as read even over different mail servers. Yet, when you delete one, it does not delete the others. Seems like if you are going to pick a behaviour, it should be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, You have read it.

I've noticed recently that if I get duplicate emails to 2 accounts, Mail is actually appearing to merge them into one email [at a user-level anyway, idk about behind the scenes]

I know of no way round this, so maybe try using Flags instead of the 'read' indicator. More work, but more reliable.

Comment: i receive more than 400 e-mails/day. every extra click counts. :( isn't there any terminal command or something?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do some **huge** digging in the menus, I don't think you can fix this. If you "mark as read" as a workaround, the e-mail will likely be marked as read on both accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The e-mail you receives has an Unique Identifier. They're the same for both as it's the "same email".

There's nothing you can do about this as Mail marks this ID as read.
Forward it yourself is an option, it will be a new UID.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Mail > Preferences > Viewing

Then uncheck “Include related messages”.